# python fabric won't allow me to pipe output to less?

Tags: python, fabric

I'm setting up fabric for the first time, and having trouble piping the output from fabric to less.  For example, if I run:

```
fabric deploy |less
```

(Where deploy is my deployment function)

I get the following error back from fabric:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

This comes from a `run()` command on the remote host.

If I add `pty=False` to the `run()` arguments, it works.  However, that means every run command, I need to add this argument.  Not to mention, I believe it has implications with prompts and entering data (obviously for those cases I won't be piping to less).

How can I fix this?  Should I just do `tty=false` for everything?

Comment: Try updating to show your actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for future reference, I resolved this by applying a patch to operations.py, as seen here:

http://code.fabfile.org/attachments/56/operations.patch

Otherwise, the code that would reproduce this problem is as follows:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.contrib.console import confirm
import re
import sys

def test():
    run('ls')
```

And the issue would come up if you did the following command:

> fab -H myhost test |less

Hope this helps someone...  I still don't understand why a bug this old still hasn't been patched in the latest release of fabric.

-Dustin